# Pass 2 arguments from drop down lists to controller.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 drop-down lists at my page, what i need it's that when both drop-down have selected values pass that values to controller. And how can i block\disable new request until the previous not finished?

Here some code that i have. 
View:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("IndexStb", "GroupStatistics", new AjaxOptions()))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUserEmail,
            new SelectList(Model.UserEmails, "Value", "Text"), "Choose user",
            new {@class = "form-control", id = "dropDown1"})

        <p><br/></p>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDate,
            new SelectList(Model.Dates, "Value", "Text"), "Choose date",
            new {@class = "form-control", id = "dropDown2"})
    }

    @section Scripts
    {
        <script>
            $("#dropDown2").on("change",
                function() {

                    var date = $(this).val();

                    $("#dropDown1").on("change",
                        function() {

                            var user = $("#dropDown1").val();

                            var url = '@Url.Action("GetStatistics", "GroupStatistics")' +
                                "?selectedDate=" +
                                date +
                                "&selectedUserEmail=" +
                                user;

                            if (user !== undefined && date !== undefined) {

                                $("#partialView").load(url,
                                    function() {
                                        $('#partialView').fadeIn('fast');
                                    });
                            }
                        });
                })
        </script>
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetStatistics(string selectedDate, string selectedUserEmail)
    {
        //some actions
        return PartialView("_MemberStatisticsPartial", testRunViewModels);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
$("#dropDown2").on("change", doSomething)

$("#dropDown1").on("change", doSomething)

function doSomething() {
    var user = $("#dropDown1").val();
    var date = $("#dropDown2").val();
    if (user !== undefined && date !== undefined) {

        var url = '@Url.Action("GetStatistics", "GroupStatistics")' +
            "?selectedDate=" +
            date +
            "&selectedUserEmail=" +
            user;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            async:false, 
            success: function (data) {
                  $("#partialView").html(data)
                  $('#partialView').fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @patilprashant6792, it works finally. One thing - i've changed request's type from HttpGet to HttpPost, and changed script a bit to:

                `$("#dropDown1").on("change", function() {

                    $("#dropDown2").on("change", doSomething);

                });`